# TLS и SSL на HTTPS работа в деталях(без openssl и других библиотек)

Tags: c++, delphi, ssl, https, tls

Для курсовой работы нужно написать алгоритм который бы подключался к сайту и делал просто GET запрос для получения информации. Алгоритмы TLS 1.3 и 2.0 (ниже не требуется).
Нужно самостоятельно написать алгоритм по которому клиент и сервер обмениваются ключами.

Я попробовал запарсил процедуру коннекта у Firefox но из за шифрования ничего не понятно на каких битах что зашифровано. К тому же как я понял начиная с TLS 1.3 браузер может сохранять сессионный ключ, мне же нужно чтобы мой клиент мог как запрашивать ключ так и подключаться с ранее полученным.

Я написал что openssl нельзя использовать, на самом деле можно - но только для крипто алгоритмов, то есть если например нужно провести какие то действия по RSA - то её можно использовать, но для процедуры рукопожатия нельзя.

То есть мне нужно самому установить соединение с сервером, передать ему запрос, получить ответ рукопожатия, понять на каких алгоритм работает сервер и уже используя их отправить ему следующий запрос - завершить рукопожатие и уже передать шифрованные заголовки GET запроса.
Будет здорово если у кто то сможет поделиться исходниками на любом языке программирования, мне бы конечно лучше C++ или Delphi.

А так же очень желательно ссылки на литературу, где написано какие последовательности байтов шифруют алгоритмы, то есть в каких позициях запроса и ответа должны быть данные и какие именно(ключи, алгоритмы, шифрования, ключевые фразы для того чтобы клиент и сервер поняли друг друга).

Comment: Коль уж попросили ссылку, то вот вам первоисточник, разбирайтесь: [The Transport Layer Security (TLS) Protocol Version 1.3](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446)

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать протоколы TLS Handshake и TLS Records. Честно сказать, я не уверен, что можно так просто взять и найти реализации, не зависящие от базовых библиотек, и прежде всего `openssl`.